# Microsoft Graph net sdk v5 SiteWithPath

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Previously I had the following code to get drive item based on sharepoint link

https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/TEAM_NAME/Shared%20Documents/Channel%20to%20sync/DocumentTree?csf=1&web=1&e=Iv84Mo

```
var teamSiteName = "TEAM_NAME";
var relativeFolderPath = "Shared%20Documents/Channel%20to%20sync/DocumentTree";

Drive rootTeamDrive = await graphServiceClient.Sites.Root.SiteWithPath($"sites/{teamsSiteName}").Drive.Request().GetAsync();

DriveItem folder = await graphServiceClient
            .Drives[rootTeamDrive.Id]
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath(relativeFolderPath)
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1693 i've created more readable solution

PS. but I needed to add Sites.Read.All permissions.

Using Regex I spitted it into three vars

```
var hostname = "DOMAIN.sharepoint.com";
var teamSiteName = "TEAM_NAME";
var relativeFolderPath = "Shared%20Documents/Channel%20to%20sync/DocumentTree";
```

And here my code

```
var path = $"/sites/{teamsSiteName}";
var site = await graphServiceClient.Sites[$"{hostname}:{path}"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { nameof(Site.Drive) };
}));

DriveItem folder = await graphServiceClient
    .Drives[site.Drive.Id]
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(relativeFolderPath)
    .GetAsync();
```